Escaping ‘@‘ in a .dat file
I need to create an insert query containing regex for the following format ‘abc@123.csv’. As ‘@‘ is a special character in .dat file nothing seems to work. Does anyone knows how to do this?
I have tried using / and // backslashes and a bunch of other things but nothing worked.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please give us more information about what you are actually trying. Which software is reading the dat-file? How can we reproduce your issue? Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
